# How to find and modify a string inside the content in WordPress that is shorter than n characters and that is preceded and followed by a newline?

Tags: php, wordpress, string, wordpress-theming

Like the title, I need a simple php code in WordPress that will search the content of every post and if it finds a string shorter than n or 60 characters inside the post and that is prededed and followed by a newline it will modify that string and it will add h2 tags around it.

Example:

> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean
>   aliquet sodales sapien, non pharetra mauris sodales quis. In non lorem
>   commodo, ullamcorper orci et, dignissim odio. Aenean pretium est in
>   neque commodo euismod. Donec sit amet ullamcorper leo. Pellentesque
>   accumsan ex vel ipsum ornare, vitae ultricies erat pretium.
>
> Example phrase to test.
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean
>   aliquet sodales sapien, non pharetra mauris sodales quis. In non lorem
>   commodo, ullamcorper orci et, dignissim odio. Aenean pretium est in
>   neque commodo euismod. Donec sit amet ullamcorper leo. Pellentesque
>   accumsan ex vel ipsum ornare, vitae ultricies erat pretium."

In this case I would like the function to only select **Example phrase to test** and add h2 tags around it.

I am fairly new to PHP.
So far I've tried but it didn't work, it simply removes all the content from the page leaving it blank:

```
function replace_content($content)
{

            $arr = explode("\n", $content);
            foreach($arr as &$value) {
                if (strlen($value) < 60) {
                    $value = str_replace("&", "<h2>. & .</h2>",$value);
                    return $value;
                }
            }


}
add_filter('the_content','replace_content');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have working solution [new replace_content function with simply test]:

```
<?php

$content = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean aliquet sodales sapien, non pharetra mauris sodales quis. In non lorem commodo, ullamcorper orci et, dignissim odio. Aenean pretium est in neque commodo euismod. Donec sit amet ullamcorper leo. Pellentesque accumsan ex vel ipsum ornare, vitae ultricies erat pretium.

Example phrase to test.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean aliquet sodales sapien, non pharetra mauris sodales quis. In non lorem commodo, ullamcorper orci et, dignissim odio. Aenean pretium est in neque commodo euismod. Donec sit amet ullamcorper leo. Pellentesque accumsan ex vel ipsum ornare, vitae ultricies erat pretium';

function replace_content($content) {
  $arr = explode("\n", $content);

  foreach ($arr as &$value) {
    if (strlen($value) < 60) {
        $value = '<h2>' . $value . '</h2>';
    }
  }

  return implode("\n", $arr);
}

echo replace_content($content);
```

## What was wrong with your code?

1. In filters in wp you need to return whole content of post, not only part which is shorther than 60 chars
2. You used wrongly str_replace, see here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php